# Convert UTC datetime to the client's local datetime using a value of timezone offset

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timezone-offset

I would like to save client's local datetime in my table.
The client can be at any place in the world.
I don't want to receive client's local datetime as a parameter to my procedure because it can be easily changed by changing the machine's datetime.
My plan is to receive only the timezone offset, add it to UTC datetime and save it like that.
Is seems a simple thing to do with `DATEADD(hour, @timezoneOffset, GETUTCDATE())`
(pseudocode of course)
What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: *" My plan is to receive only the timezone offset"* Because that can't be easily changed by changing the client's local timezone..? (It can be, just as easily).

Comment: Also, if you want data that's timezone related, use `timezoneoffset`. Don't add hours to the UTC time; the time will be wrong. `10:00:00Z` <> `12:00:00Z` (obviously).

Comment: @Larnu: You're correct. It doesn't resolve the problem completely. But still currently it's better than nothing at all....:(

Comment: It just *changes* the problem. Capture the local time, with the timezone, and store it in a `datetimeoffset`, and then ensure you store the UTC time as well. Then you have both and can find anomalies.